# APM Planner on Linux/Ubuntu "open from file" not working

Tags: ardupilot

I can't open parameter list with APM Planner.

Moreover I can't find anyone with same problem.
I run it on Ubuntu/trusty 14.04

It does not see files with any extensions including `param` and `txt` downloaded from internet or created with my version of APM Planner.

Any ideas how can I fix it?

[image]

**PS** `ls -la` from terminal

```
user@laptop:~/apmplanner2/parameters$ ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Dec  9 12:57 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 user user 4096 Dec  9 21:05 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 6881 Dec  9 12:57 paramter.param
```

I have `param`, `txt` files in Downloads folder also.

**PS**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure those files are there and they are not hidden? If you put `*.*` in `File name:` field, does it show the files? Can you post what you would see if you go to the terminal, go to that directory and do an `ls`?

Comment: Yes. I am sure. I was able to upload from Mac version. On Ubuntu QGroundControl is able to upload. I was not able to see `param`, `txt` files downloaded from internet or saved from APM Planner.

Comment: It's strange. What happens if you type `paramter.param` in the "File name:" field and just hit "Open"? Does it open the file correctly?

Comment: Open button is inactive. I will add screenshot that I typed it correctly.

Comment: Did you run and install the program with the right _rights_ (_user_, **root**)?!?!

Comment: Yes. I installed it from `.deb` and it is not possible to install it without sudoing.